# How to change the Cinnamon system theme from the command line?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, cinnamon

How can I change the Cinnamon system theme from the commandline?

Answer (score 2):

yesterday I first-time installed cinnamon on Ubuntu and asked the identical question(s). Here's what I have found so far.

**Question 2: How can I change the Cinnamon system theme from the commandline?**

Answer 2:
You can change cinnamon theme settings in a terminal with:
**gsettings**

1. To get allowed values gsettings, you can first set them via the GUI:
   **cinnamon-settings themes**
2. Then you filter for that new value across all gsettings - here Menta:
   **gsettings list-recursively | grep -i Menta**

Some examples:

```
        gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface clock-show-date true

        gsettings set org.cinnamon.theme name 'Menta'

        gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'menta'

        gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Menta'
```

P.S:
From above screenshot to the original question I deduct, you were asking

**Question 1: How to change the terminal settings from command line?**

Answer 1: This works via **dconf**.

1. check what terminal you are using: gnome-terminal or mate-terminal

   ```
       [ ! -z `which mate-terminal` ] && echo "Terminal:mate" || \
       [ ! -z `which gnome-terminal` ] && echo "Terminal:gnome" || \
       echo "Terminal:??"
   ```

Example for gnome-terminal:

```
        GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_ID=`gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default  | cut -d "'" -f 2`

        GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_PATH="/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_ID"

        dconf write "$GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_PATH/background-color" \"#FDF6E3\"

        dconf write "$GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_PATH/foreground-color" \"#657B83\"

        dconf write "$GNOME_TERMINAL_PROFILE_PATH/use-theme-colors" false
```

Have Fun!

Volker Fröhlich

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and select the three lines on the top bar:

[image: Terminal Menu]

Then select Preferences - you can change the theme here:

[image]

Hope that helps?

Comment: How does changing the `terminal` theme address the question that was asked?

Comment: It doesn't but it does answer the question as it was before it was edited 